# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid column name 'PayasYouGo'

Tags: model-view-controller, entity-framework-migrations

I am currently following Mosh Hamedami tutorial on Seeding the Database using code first migration. Unfortunately I came with this error `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid column name 'PayasYouGo'`. I have tried re-creating my model but nothing seems to work.

The Model:

```
public class MembershipType

    {
        public byte Id { get; set; }
        public short SignUpFee { get; set; }
        public byte DurationInMonths { get; set; }
        public byte DiscountRate { get; set; }
        public string MembershipName { get; set; }
    }
```

The Migration Code

```
public partial class PopulateMembership : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        Sql("INSERT INTO MembershipTypes (Id, SignUpFee, DurationInMonths, DiscountRate, MembershipName) VALUES (1, 0, 0, 0, PayasYouGo)");
        Sql("INSERT INTO MembershipTypes (Id, SignUpFee, DurationInMonths, DiscountRate, MembershipName) VALUES (2, 30, 1, 10, Monthly)");
        Sql("INSERT INTO MembershipTypes (Id, SignUpFee, DurationInMonths, DiscountRate, MembershipName) VALUES (3, 90, 3, 15, Quarterly)");
        Sql("INSERT INTO MembershipTypes (Id, SignUpFee, DurationInMonths, DiscountRate, MembershipName) VALUES (4, 300, 12, 20, Annual)");
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
    }
}
```

[The Database Migrated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hd77s.png)

What am I doing wrong here? What is causing this error? What does this error mean? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wanted to supply a *string* but instead gave SQL Server a *name*.

String literals in SQL Server are surrounded by single quote characters:

```
    Sql(@"INSERT INTO MembershipTypes
          (Id, SignUpFee, DurationInMonths, DiscountRate, MembershipName)
          VALUES (1, 0, 0, 0, 'PayasYouGo')");
```

(If it had worked as you expected, consider how you would have struggled if you wanted to insert a string that *contained* commas, brackets, white space, etc)

Comment: Oh my God! I feel very stupid right now. I forgot the basics. Thanks for the help. It worked like a charm.